# How to run an empty background process with a specific name?

Tags: windows, process, taskmanager

I want to have a certain process always running in the background so it will be viewable in the Task Manager of windows, with the specific name I give it.

The process shouldn't do anything really, all I care about is to see the process name whenever I open the task manager and choose "processes".

One way to achieve this is to copy Notepad.exe , change its name to something and then run it. The problem is I don't want to have an open window of notepad everytime I'm using the PC. I need it to run on background.

If it matters, I have Windows 7.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any development skills or a preferred programming environment?

Comment: Yes, I'm a developer. C# and Perl can fit.

Comment: I thought about creating a Windows Service but I donno if there's a reason to go that far, and I might want several more processes (with different names), so I don't want to create a service for each one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow
)
{
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    return 0;
}
```

This is the most simple Windows program. It does absolutely nothing and does not consume CPU.

I can't imagine why you want it, but this is what you describe!

Comment: David, thanks for your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but compiling this C / C++ program into an exe will still end up having a window open (or minimized), right?

Comment: @yellowblood No it will not. There is no call to CreateWindow and so there is no Window. You could alternatively write it with an infinite while loop that called Sleep(VERY_LARGE_NUMBER). This really is the perfect answer to your question. You've asked how to create a program that does nothing!!

Comment: sorry for the complete noob question, but how do I compile it? I downloaded GCC ("mingw32" to be exact) but it doesn't find the stdafx.h lib when I try to compile it as a cpp file.

Comment: I built it with MSVC. mingw32 should be fine too. Try it with #include <windows.h> instead. But you need to make sure it outputs a GUI app rather than a console APP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal C# version:

```
static class Program
{
    [System.STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

You can compile this from the command line:

csc /target:winexe MyProg.cs

Answer (score 0):

Well if a minimized DOS window doesn't bother you then this DOS command will be very light weight and will do the job for you: `start /min more`

Comment: The "start /min" command is really cool, but I don't like seeing the actual window. I want it to be a permanent process in my PC that I will never have to worry about :)

Comment: Hmm if minimized DOS windows is an issue then you can start any of the standard IM programs (eg: Gtalk, MSN messenger, Pidgin etc) without signing them. They will be in the task bar without opening any window and you can still see that process in taskbar.